# Error message near CREATE - Insering no record in place_info table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database class in which i am trying to make 3 tables, all tableso are created perfectly but i am unable to identify why no record is been inserted in third table. it gives me the error. i am posting my code here. please help me identifying what is the issue?

Database.java

```
package com.example.nearbyplaces;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;



import android.R.integer;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String db_name = "nearby_place";
    private static final int db_version = 2;

    //tables
        private static final String table_placetypes = "placetypes";
        private static final String table_places = "table_places";
        private static final String table_placeInfo = "table_placeinfo";

        //column names
        private static final String type_id = "type_id";
        private static final String type_name = "type_name";
        private static final String place_id = "place_id";
        private static final String place_name = "place_name";
        private static final String place_address = "place_address";
        private static final String place_contact = "place_contact";
        private static final String info_id = "info_id";


        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        // create table queries
        String create_table_placetypes = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_placetypes + "("
                + type_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + type_name + " TEXT" + ")";



        String create_table_places = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_places (place_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, place_name TEXT, type_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES table_placetypes(type_id))";

        String create_table_placeinfo = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_placeinfo (info_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, place_address TEXT, place_contact TEXT, place_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES table_places(place_id) )";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL(create_table_placetypes);

            Log.d("creating", "placetypes created");
            db.execSQL(create_table_places);
            Log.d("creating", "places created");
            db.execSQL(create_table_placeinfo);
            Log.d("creating", "place_info created");

        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_placetypes);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_places);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + create_table_placeinfo);
            onCreate(db);

        }
        // add placetypes 
        void addplacetypes (placetypes pt) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(type_name, pt.getTypename());

            db.insert(table_placetypes, null, values);
            db.close();

        }

         // Getting single placetypes
        placetypes getPlacetypes(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(table_placetypes, new String[] {type_id,
                    type_name }, type_id + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            placetypes pt = new placetypes(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1));
            // return contact
            return pt;
        }

     // Getting All placetypes
        public List<placetypes> getAllPlacetypes() {
            List<placetypes> placetypesList = new ArrayList<placetypes>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    placetypes pt = new placetypes();
                    pt.setTypeid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    pt.setTypename(cursor.getString(1));


                    //String name = cursor.getString(1);

                    //MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);
                    // Adding contact to list
                    placetypesList.add(pt);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return placetype list
            return placetypesList;
    }

        // Getting placetypes Count
        public int getPlacetypesCount() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            cursor.close();

            // return count
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

        public void addplaces(places p) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(place_name, p.getPlace_name());
            values.put(type_id, p.getT_id());

            Log.d("Type ID", String.valueOf(p.getT_id()));
            db.insert(table_places, null, values);
            db.close();

        }

        places getPlaces(int pid) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(table_places, new String[] {place_id, place_name,type_id}, place_id + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(pid) } , null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null)
                 cursor.moveToFirst();

            places p = new places(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
                    cursor.getString(2)

                    );

            cursor.close();

            return p;

        }

        public List<places> getAllPlaces(String typeName) {

            List<places> placeList = new ArrayList<places>();
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id=table_places.type_id "; 
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places WHERE table_places.type_id="+Integer.toString(typeid);
            //String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM table_places WHERE table_places.place_name = " +typeName+ "INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id = table_places.type_id";
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id = table_places.type_id WHERE table_places.place_name = " + typeName + "";
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_places;
            String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id=table_places.type_id WHERE placetypes.type_name='"+typeName+"'";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


            if(cursor.moveToFirst() )
            {
                do{
                places p = new places();
                /*p.setT_id(cursor.getColumnIndex(type_id));
                p.setPlace_id(cursor.getColumnIndex(place_id));
                p.setPlace_name(cursor.getColumnIndex(place_name));
                */

                p.setPlace_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                p.setPlace_name(cursor.getString(1));
                p.setT_id(cursor.getInt(2));

                /*String t_id = cursor.getString(4);
                String p_name = cursor.getString(2);
                String p_address = cursor.getString(3);
                String p_contact = cursor.getString(1);*/

                placeList.add(p);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            return placeList;
        }

        public int getPlaceCount () {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_places;
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            cursor.close();

            return cursor.getCount();
        }

        public void addPlaceInfo(placeInfo pi) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            values.put(place_address,pi.getAddress());
            values.put(place_contact, pi.getContact());
            values.put(place_id, pi.getPlace_id());
            Log.d("Place ID", String.valueOf(pi.getPlace_id()));
            db.insert(create_table_placeinfo, null, values);
            db.close();

        }

        placeInfo getPlaceInfo (int infoid) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(create_table_placeinfo, new String[] {info_id, place_address, place_contact, place_id}, info_id + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(infoid)}, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            placeInfo pi = new placeInfo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));

        cursor.close();
        return pi;
             }

       public List<placeInfo> getAllPlaceInfo(String place_name) {

           List<placeInfo> placeInfoList = new ArrayList<placeInfo>();
           String SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_placeinfo INNER JOIN table_places ON table_place.place_id=table_placeinfo.place_id WHERE table_places.place_id= '"+place_name+"'";
           SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(create_table_placeinfo, null);

           if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

               do {

                   placeInfo pi = new placeInfo();
                   pi.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                   pi.setAddress(cursor.getString(1));
                   pi.setContact(cursor.getString(2));
                   pi.setPlace_id(cursor.getInt(3));

                   placeInfoList.add(pi);

               }while(cursor.moveToNext());

           }

           cursor.close();
           return placeInfoList;


       } 

       public int getPlaceInfoCount () {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_placeInfo;
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            cursor.close();

            return cursor.getCount();
        }


}
```

MainActivity3.java

```
package com.example.nearbyplaces;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent check = getIntent();
        String x = check.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.PLACE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        if(db.getAllPlaceInfo(x).isEmpty()) {

            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

            db.addPlaceInfo(new placeInfo("QM Building, Plot# BC 15, Block, Khayaban-e-Roomi, Clifton", "111-241-241",1));
             Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all places..");

            if(ArrayofName.isEmpty()) {

                List<placeInfo> placeInfo = db.getAllPlaceInfo(x);

                for(placeInfo pi : placeInfo) 
                {
                    String log = "Id: " + pi.getPlace_id() + "Address: " + pi.getAddress() +  "COntact: " + pi.getContact();

                      //Writing Places to log
                    Log.d("Address: ", log);
                    Log.d("Contact: ", log);


                    System.out.println(log);
                    ArrayofName.add(pi.getAddress());
                    ArrayofName.add(pi.getContact());

                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);


                }
            }

        }




    }

}
```

Logcat

```
10-12 08:14:44.061: D/Insert:(5401): Inserting ..
10-12 08:14:44.081: D/Place ID(5401): 1
10-12 08:14:44.081: E/SQLiteLog(5401): (1) near "CREATE": syntax error
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401): Error inserting place_id=1 place_address=QM Building, Plot# BC 15, Block, Khayaban-e-Roomi, Clifton place_contact=111-241-241
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_placeinfo (info_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, place_address TEXT, place_contact TEXT, place_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES table_places(place_id) )(place_id,place_address,place_contact) VALUES (?,?,?)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at com.example.nearbyplaces.DatabaseHandler.addPlaceInfo(DatabaseHandler.java:235)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at com.example.nearbyplaces.MainActivity3.onCreate(MainActivity3.java:37)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 08:14:44.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(5401):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your following line from method `addPlaceInfo(placeInfo pi)`,

`db.insert(create_table_placeinfo, null, values);` //it is using the create query

should be

`db.insert(table_placeInfo, null, values);` //using the table name

Answer (score 0):

Your function addplaceinfo has

```
values.put(place_address,pi.getAddress());
            values.put(place_contact, pi.getContact());
            values.put(place_id, pi.getPlace_id());
```

While from main activity you are inserting values

```
db.addPlaceInfo(new placeInfo("QM Building, Plot# BC 15, Block, Khayaban-e-Roomi, Clifton", "111-241-241",1));
```

Comment: So what is the issue in this?

Comment: oops, got it, i missed out the foreign key